# C++ user entry and error handling

Tags: c++, error-handling

I am currently writing a knights tour program and I am trying to think of the best way to handle the problem I am running into.  My goal is to prompt the user to enter in several inputs for a starting place on the board.  This means that the user needs to be able to type in several numbers which in my opinion, this means I need an empty array that can accept the input.  I am coding in C++ and this is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int greeting(){

cout << "Welcome to the Knights Tour! Please, enter your desired starting places." <<
endl << "Enter any numbers 1-64, and type -1 to start." << endl << endl;


int board[8][8] = {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},
                {9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16},
                {17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24},
                {25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32},
                {33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40},
                {41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48},
                {49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56},
                {57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64}
                };

for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++){

        for(int column=0; column<8; column++){
            cout << setw(3) << board[row][column] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
}
cout << endl;

}

int main(){
greeting();
}
```

I have tried several methods to accept the user input but what I am ultimately trying to do is allow only integer input from 1-64 and allow the user to type -1 to exit the loop.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
int position = 0;
std::string line;
do
{
    while (std::cout << "Select position 1-64, or type -1 to exit\n" &&
           std::getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        position = 0;
        if (iss >> position &&
            (position == -1 ||
             position 1 <= position && position <= 64))
        {
            char c;
            if (!(iss >> c))
                break;
            std::cerr << "trailing character also found on input line, please try again\n";
        }
        else
            std::cerr << "you entered an invalid position, please try again\n";
    }
    if (1 <= position && position <= 64)
    {
        // do/call your position-related work here...
    }
} while (position != -1 && std::cin);
```